# Rails link_to and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 not working on iPhone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

Since upgrading my Rails app from JQueryMobile 1.0.1 to 1.1.0 my link_to´s with methods other than :get are not working any longer on iPhone Safari.

Say i´m on /profile page and have the following code:

```
=link_to 'Videos', videos_path(@video), :method => :post
```

In source inspector i can see that Rails generates correctly an anchor tag to f.e: /videos/9
But when i click this link on iPhone Safari i get a server error:

```
Started POST "/profile" for 10.0.0.7 at 2012-04-23 17:51:16 +0200
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/profile/9"):
```

'profile' is the url of the current page and the link_to tag points to 'videos_path', so instead of getting a post to videos/ i get a post to the current url 'profile/'

With jqm 1.0.1 the links are working on laptop and iPhone Safari
Since jqm 1.1.0 links are working on laptop but not on iPhone Safari.

Do i miss some new attributes like data-method?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have an good answer to this but:
a) I have experienced exactly the same problem
b) I have confirmed that downgrading to jQM 1.0.1 fixes the problem

I too would like to know if I missed something in the transition to 1.1?